# Connect app to backend on server via wifi with no internet connection

Tags: android, ios, web-services, local-network

Here is my problem, I need to have a webserver on a wifi with no internet connection. Now I have developed a web app so i can access it through my android and/or ios devices.

The issue happens with devices that have mobile data available, it seems to look for the local ip address of the webserver on the internet.

Is there a way to tell it to look on the local network? I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

On api-21 and up, you can use the [`openConnection()` method of the Network class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#openConnection(java.net.URL)), and open a connection that is specific to the WiFi network

From the documentation:

> Opens the specified URL on this Network, such that all traffic will be
>   sent on this Network.

Here's how to use it:

```
HttpURLConnection con = null;
try {
    URL myurl = new URL("192.168.xx.x");
    con = (HttpURLConnection) NetworkingUtil.getWifiNetwork().openConnection(myurl);

    InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();

    //..............

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```